# How can i raise popup only in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have div element.In Div,it contains lables,textboxes,combobox.
I want to write event to button.When i click the button, the popup will raise(that popup contains div data).How is it possible in JavaScript?Please Help me.

sample code:

```
<div id="cmbYardNames" title="Selection" runat="server">
<p><label id="lblselectApmc">Checkpost</label></p>
<asp:DropDownList ID="combyardname" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" 
        style="width:155px;" class="txtstyle">       
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: k sure i got good answers by using stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Basically to "raise" a popup like div, you need to set it's position to absolute, give it a high z-Index to make sure it'll be above any other element, and center it given the viewport position.

You might want to check dojo toolkit, there is a dijit.Dialog that is doing pretty much exactly what you want.